# Nodejs Parallel programming using threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, meteor, parallel-processing

I am using nodejs for a CPU intensive task ,which basicly generates large amount of data and stores it in a file. I am streaming the data to output files as it is generated for a single type of data.

**Aim** : I want to make the task of generating this data for multiple types of data in parallel (utilizing my multi-core cpu to its best).Without each of process having its own heap memory .Thus providing with larger process memory and increased speed of execution.

I was planning to use node [fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers) which is also  used by [meteor js](https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor/) for its own callback handling.But I am not sure if this will achieve what I want,as in one of the [video on meteor fibers by *Chris Mather*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWJ8LIzQMHY) mentions at the end that eventually everything is single threaded and node fibers somehow manges the same single threaded event loop  to provide its functionality.

So,

- Does this mean that if I use node fibers I wont be running my task in
  parallel ,thus not utilizing my cpu cores ?
- Does node [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) will help me in achieving the
  functionality I desire.As is mentioned on modules home page which
  says that ,webworker threads will run on seperate/parallel cpu
  process ,thus providing multi-threading in real sense ??
- As ending question ,Does this mean that node.js is not advisable for
  such CPU intensive tasks ?

*note : I dont want to use asynchronous code structuring libs which are presented as threads,but infact just add syntatical sugar over same async code, as the tasks are largely CPU intensive .I have already used async capabilities to max .*

**// Update 1 (based on answer for clusters )**

Sorry I forgot to mention this ,but problem with clusters I faced is :

- Complex to load balance the amount of work I have in a way which makes sure  a particular set of parallel tasks execute before certain other tasks.
- Not sure if clusters really do what I want ,referring to [these lines on webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads#why-not-multiple-processes) npm homepage

> The "can't block the event loop" problem is inherent to Node's evented model. No matter how many Node processes you have running as a Node-cluster, it won't solve its issues with CPU-bound tasks.

..... any light on how ..would be helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to implement multiple threads, you should find it much easier to use multiple processes with Node.js

See, for example, the [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module. This allows you to easily run the same js code in multiple processes, e.g. one per core, and collect their results / be notified once they're completed.

If cluster does more than you need, then you can also just call [`fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) directly.

---

If you must have thread-parallelism rather than process-, then you may want to look at writing an [async native](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) module. Then you have access to the libuv thread pool (though starving it may reduce I/O performance) or can fork your own threads as you wish (but then you're on your own for synchronising with the rest of Node).

---

**After update 1**

For load balancing, if what cluster does isn't working for you, then you can just do it yourself with fork, as I mentioned. The source for cluster is available.

For the other point, it means if the task is truly CPU-bound then there's no advantage Node will give you over other technologies, other than being simpler if everything else is using Node. The only option you have is to make sure you're using all the available CPU resources, which a worker pool will give you. If you're already using Node then the easiest options are using the ones it's already got (cluster or libuv). If they're not sufficient then yeah, you'll have to find something else.

Regardless of technology, it remains true that multi-process parallelism is a lot easier than multi-thread parallelism.

Note: despite what you say, you definitely do want to use async code precisely because it is CPI-intensive, otherwise your tasks will block all I/O. You do not want this to happen.

Comment: Does this mean that there isnt any library whihc will provide multi-threaded parallelism in node..as compared to other technologies

Comment: There are, but in many people's opinion they're a very bad idea. JavaScript is not designed for that.

Comment: What about *webworker-threads* npm module  .. One of concern I have is the statement it makes saying ,cluster still will cause the node event-loop to go slow and wont help for speed up .. ?

Comment: Some general advice: **don't believe anything anyone says about performance until you have tested your exact use-case**. If your server is sitting there with 1 core at 100% and 15 cores doing nothing and all your I/O waiting for data, I'm pretty sure you'll see a speedup.

Comment: So I will be better of using clustering rather than multi-threading...is what you are saying?

Comment: You will be better off using multiple processes rather than multiple threads (it will be easier, less will go wrong, and the bugs you do get will be simpler). Clustering is one (high level) way to implement multiple processes.

Comment: So what are the use cases for libraries like fibers (used vastly in meteor js)..if they just tweak the event loop ...without any performance improvement..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112065/discussion-between-orangedog-and-damitj07).